# jeditable loadurl: referencing css id or just passing in variables as needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, jinja2, jeditable

I have this on my page:

```
$('.editable-question').editable('{{my_identifier}}/form_item/edit',{
                    //loadurl: 'example/restful/url/in/app/{{???????????????}}',
                    type   : 'textarea',
                    cancel : 'Cancel',
                    submit : 'OK',                  
                    name   : 'edit_this',
                  });
```

I'm using jeditable, in a Flask application inside a jinja template. The problem is,  I need to pass in information to the 'loadurl' to retrieve unformatted markdown text, but I have no idea how to get something from the css into that loadurl statement:

```
<div id="f4d629f9f0" class="editable-question" style="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
</div>
```

this case I want to get the css id into {{????????}}. How is this normally done? Seems like a common question but I have not one turned up one yet or an answer. More rtfm'ing I suppose.

A less pressing issue is that I'll need to remove my js from the jinja templates at some point, but I'm unsure about how I get the variables I need into page and then into the js: I guess hidden elements and/or url reference that js grabs the variables as needed.

edit:

I've ended up with something like:

```
$('.editable-question').editable('/form_item/edit',{
                    id: 'my_id',
                    loadurl: 'node',
                    type   : 'textarea',
                    cancel : 'Cancel',
                    submit : 'OK',                  
                    name   : 'edit_this',
                  });
```

and my_id gets passed as a url param (?my_id={{css id}}) by jeditable, but it feels dirty, I'd prefer a restful url, but need to just get things done atm so moving on.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand your questions correct? But I came up with three answers:

1) If you include your js in your HTML template, jinja can render the HTML and the js. For jinja it does not matter what kind of data is in the template HTML, TXT, CSS or JS.

2) You can pass your variables in hidden fields of your HTML template and use dom manipulation (like jquery) to get the variables from the dom.

3) You can include a small javascript in your HTML, which contains only a function with the variables. In your external javascript files you can access these functions to get the variables.

To get the idea, here is a part of a HTML template to configure the codemirror editor and using jinja in the HTML and the inline js:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/jinjacms/static/jinjacms.css"> 
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/codemirror/theme/rubyblue.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function editor(id)
{
        CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById(id), {
        theme: "rubyblue", 
        lineNumbers: true, 
        mode: {{ mode }},
        {% if readonly %}readOnly: "nocursor",{% endif %} 
        tabSize: 4,
        indentUnit: 4,
        indentWithTabs: true,
        tabMode: "shift"
      });
}
</script>
<style>.CodeMirror {border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;}</style>
<title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body onload="editor('text_data');">
```

Comment: My main question originally involved getting a css div id into the url used by loadurl, which may be one of many on the page and not something I'd have passed into the template js

Comment: If you can select the div (f.i. using a mouse or focus event) you can can get the id of the current selected element. Is this what you mean?

Comment: partly -- I need to use 'loadurl', and I need to provide a restful relative url 'node/(node_id)' where node_id is pulled from the css id it resides in e.g. <div id="node-1234dfas">stuff</div>